# DVI-I to VGA adapter not working (Analog signal issue?)

Tags: vga, dvi, display-driver, display-adapter, analog

I have two monitors that have *only* VGA imputs on them. The computer I'm plugging them into has VGA and DVI-I outputs on the motherboard. To connect the DVI-I to the second VGA monitor I'm using the standard run-of-the-mill adapter that is really easy to find.

It has all 24 pins plus the '-' shaped pin and the four pins surrounding the '-'. I'm positive it is the correct adapter. I have tested it with another computer and it *does* work. However, it refuses to function on the computer it needs to. The computer won't work with a similar adapter either.

I've talked with an IT guy I knew and he said that the problem wasn't something I was doing. The DVI-I port will output a signal through a DVI-D cable, and I can also send data by using a DVI-D to HDMI cable and then a HDMI to VGA converter box, so I think that it is having an issue sending an analog signal.

Any ideas?

Specs you might want:

- Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6530D
- Motherboard: BIOSTAR

---

*Please remember that kindness and respect are greatly appreciated. Also* constructive *criticism*.

Comment: The mobos that I've used that have both VGA and DVI-I connectors only had one RAMDAC.  That means that if you use the VGA output, then only a digital output is available for a second monitor using the DVI connector.